# $\text{If } x(x+y+z)=20,y(x+y+z)=30 \text{ and } z(x+y+z)=50 \text{ then the value of } 2(x+y+z) is:$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x(x+y+z)=20$, $y(x+y+z)=30$ and $z(x+y+z)=50$ then what is the value of $2(x+y+z)$?

*Ans.* $20$

I have tried the following:

$$ \frac{20}{x}=\frac{30}{y}=\frac{50}{z}$$
From which I get:
$$x:y:z=2:3:5$$
Now,
$$2(x+y+z)=\frac{20}{x}+\frac{30}{y}$$
$$\implies\frac{20y+30x}{xy}$$
$$\implies\frac{20*\frac{3z}{5}+30*\frac{2z}{5}}{\frac{2z}{5}\frac{3z}{5}}$$
Which gives me
$$\frac{100}{z}$$

Back to the 3rd equation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x(x+y+z)=20,\\ y(x+y+z)=30\\ z(x+y+z)=50\\ $$ by summing all these three eqatuations$$\left( x+y+z \right) \left( z+y+x \right) =100\\ { \left( x+y+z \right)  }^{ 2 }=100\\ x+y+z=\pm 10$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead $$x(x+y+z)+y(x+y+z)+z(x+y+z)$$

Comment: Sir, how would I know that my method wont work?

Comment: @Soumee I'm not sure what you did after the "Now," anyway you could also put $x=2k,y=3k,z=5k$ from $x:y:z=2:3:5$ and find $k$

Comment: Yes,t that's possible too... I have taken 'two' $(x+y+z)$ , and added them and then replaced x and y in terms of z..In that case z is left in the denominator , which is leading me back to the third equation given in question. I am wondering why this method of mine is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, follow the equations you get:

$${y(x+y+z)\over x(x+y+z)}={30\over20} \implies {y\over x}={3\over2}\implies y={3\over2}x\\{z(x+y+z)\over x(x+y+z)}={50\over20} \implies {z\over x}={5\over2}\implies z={5\over 2}x\\x(x+y+z)=20\implies x\left(x+{3\over2}x+{5\over2}x\right)=20\implies{10\over 2}x^2=20\implies x^2=4\\\implies x=\pm2\\\implies y=\pm3\\\implies z=\pm5$$  all have to be of same sign in this case and you get :

$$x+y+z=\pm10\implies2(x+y+z)=\boxed{\pm20}$$

Comment: In theory, we could assume, that  since both parts of the original rational expression divide by (x+y+z), and the fraction they equal has a common factor of 10 then (x+y+z)=10, and get 2(x+y+z)=20, but then that doesn't have to be the case necessarily also multiple solutions exist so you would have found only one.